# How to solve layout issues in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, apk

Here the image from my mobile:
[image: image from my mobile]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Miles"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="46dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Km"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="46dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="140dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvMilesToKm"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="Convert Miles To Km"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="209dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvKmToMiles"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:text="Convert Km To Miles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="65dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMiles"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:text="Convert Km To Miles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="179dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="46dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextKm"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="179dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This maybe a small error i did , but what am i missing so the interface appears to be overlapped . Im using Android Studio to develop this But the reference design looks alright unless i run it on emulator or my mobile itself . Im guessing im not wrong in coding the layouts n i even tried to change the way the layouts can be written

Comment: edit your question with layout file

Comment: If you want to get help you with your code. Show what you have tried.

Comment: Im trying to edit the question

Comment: it looks like you don't have constraints set, so everything floats to the top left Definitely show the layout's code

Comment: please add layout code

Comment: Im trying to share the code as well.  I have added layout code maybe the value has something to do with it

Comment: Sinchana Your layout widgets have no constraints thats why they are showing up like that... it may look fine in design tab but not in actual device ... follow some tutorials on ConstraintLayout

Comment: oh thank you AgentP , for mentioning where im wrg i would definitely try to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout has no constraints. Please review [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#developer-guide) on the valid `ConstraintLayout` XML attributes you can use to layout views relative to each other within a ConstraintLayout. You are looking for attributes like `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`.